# Would it make sense to share the layers (except the last one) of the neural networks in Double DQN?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, implementation, double-dqn

Context: [Double Q-learning](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2010/file/091d584fced301b442654dd8c23b3fc9-Paper.pdf) was introduced to prevent the maximization bias from q-learning. Instead of learning a single Q-network, we can learn two (or in general $K > 1$) and our Q-estimate would be the min across all these Q-networks.

Question:
Does it make sense to share the layers of these Q-networks (except the last layer)?

So, instead of having 2 networks of size [64, 64, 2] (with ~8.5K parameters in total) we can have one network of size [64, 64, 4] (with ~4.3K params).

I couldn't see much of a downside to this, but all the implementations I've seen keep two completely different networks.